# Producing equal images in Python and Matlab - How to?

Tags: python, image, matlab, grayscale

I am working on a project that involves both Matlab and Python and I am producing some images. Altough the matrixes I want to transform into images are the same, the images I get are not the same. I assume this has something to do with the equivalence between Python and Matlab commands for displaying images and thus this is why I am here.

**MATLAB CODE:**

```
fmn0 = imread('cameraman.tif');
fmn=double(ifftshift(fmn0,2));
Fun=fftshift(fft(fmn,[],2),2); 

imshow(real(Fun))
```

*MATLAB OUTPUT:*

[image]

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

def row_wise_fft(A):
    A = np.asarray(A)
    rowWiseFFT = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1]), dtype='complex')
    for i in range(0, A.shape[0]):
        rowWiseFFT[i, :] = np.fft.fft(A[i,:])
    return rowWiseFFT

def row_wise_ifftshift(A):
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        A[i] = np.fft.ifftshift(A[i])
    return A

def row_wise_fftshift(A):
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        A[i] = np.fft.fftshift(A[i])
    return A

fmn = cv2.imread("cameraman.tif", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

fun = row_wise_fftshift(row_wise_fft(row_wise_ifftshift(fmn)))

plt.set_cmap("Greys_r")
plt.imshow(fun.real)
```

*PYHTON OUTPUT:*

[image]

I can see some similarities, but how would one leave the Python output as the exact same as the Matlab one? Note that the fun matrixes are the exact same.

Comment: do `imshow(real(Fun),[])` and see the magic of color autoadjusting go away!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Your comment was usefull and it works if I wanted to turn my Matlab output into the python output I already have. But I want to turn the python output into the matlab one, not the other way around!

Comment: well.... then do the opposite??? let me rephrase then `do plt.clims([0 1])` to magically turn on the same color adjusting that MATLAB!

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the help! If you want to elaborate an answer below it would be my pleasure to mark it as the right one! Just one note: I used `plt.clim([0,1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB autoscales the output to `[0 1]`, so most of your data in the MATLAB plot is extremely saturated and not really visible.

do `imshow(real(Fun),[])` to remove the saturation and actually see all your data (MATLAB).

do `plt.clim([0,1])` to saturate the visualization of your data in python.

You can also just give either MATLAB or python a different range of values to visualize (e.g. [0, 15])